# How to append the value in array if key is same

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have an associative array as

```
[name]->user1,
[class_code]->bsc,
[name]->user2,
[class_code]->msc,
[name]->user1,
[class_code]->mca
```

Now, i want result as

```
[name]->user1,
[class_code]->bsc,
mca
[name]->user2,
[class_code]->msc
```

Means if name is same then append the class_code to first one. How should I do that?
My array is

```
 [1] =stdClass Object
        ([class_code] =Maths
            [userid] =365
            [avatar] =default.jpg
            [username] =user2
        )

    [2] =stdClass Object
        (
            [class_code] =Maths
            [userid] = 364
            [avatar] =default.jpg
            [username] =user1
        )

 [3] =stdClass Object
        (
            [class_code] =MCA
            [userid] =364
            [avatar] =default.jpg
            [username] =user1
        )

    [4] =stdClass Object
        (
            [class_code] =MCA
            [userid] =365
            [avatar] =default.jpg
            [username] =user2
        )
```

Now, while displaying result i want to display records of for ex. user2 as

```
username:user2
avatar
classcode :MCA,Maths
```

and not

```
username:user2
avatar
classcode :MCA
username:user2
avatar
classcode :Maths
```

how can I do that?

Comment: How can you have an associative array where different entries have the same key? Please post a `var_export` of your array.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have two values with the same key.  Otherwise php wouldn't know what to give you if you asked for $myarray['name'].

You could use nested arrays instead.

eg

```
[0]-> 
  [name]->user1,
  [class_code]->bsc,mca,
[1]->
  [name]->user2,
  [class_code]->msc
```

or you could do something like this

```
[user1]->bsc, mca
[user2]->msc
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have both values in there, you should consider using an array in there

```
array(
   "name"=>"user1,
   "class_code"=>"array('mca','bsc'),
   "name"=>"user2,
   "class_code"=>"msc"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

if `[class_code]` must contain a string, you can try

```
$array[$key] .= $value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the whole array multidimensional:

```
$users = array(
   0 = array(
       "name"=>"user1",
       "class_code"=>"bsc"
   ),
   1 = array(
       "name"=>"user2",
       "class_code"=>"msc"
   )
);
```

Retrieving a value:

```
$users[1][name]              // Returns 'user2'
$users[0][class_code]        // Returns 'bsc'
```

Cycling through values:

```
foreach($users as $user => $attributes) {
    echo "$user: $attributes[name] ($attributes[class_code])<br />";
}

/*
Prints:
    0: user1 (bsc)
    1: user2 (msc)
*/
```